# SQL Server : join table to itself to show data horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains students marks (StudentsID, Subject, Year, Mark).

I want to display the Marks horizontally for the same Student, subject but different year.

The problem I have is that not all subjects available in all years, I mean the student can take different subject every year. and I want to show them all in one table horizontally.

Example:

[image: image 1]

I tried this query

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.StudentID, dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.[Student Name], 
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.SubjectName, dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.AcademicYear, 
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.Class, dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.Term1, dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.Term2, 
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.Term3, dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.Final, 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.AcademicYear AS AcademicYear2, 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.Class AS Class2, 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.Term1 AS [Term1-2], 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.Term2 AS [Term2-2], 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.Term3 AS [Term3-2], 
    New_Portal_OldMarks_1.Final AS [Final-2]
FROM
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks AS New_Portal_OldMarks_1 ON dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.StudentID = New_Portal_OldMarks_1.StudentID 
                                                     AND dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.SubjectName = New_Portal_OldMarks_1.SubjectName
WHERE     
    (dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks.StudentID = 1004000)
ORDER BY 
    AcademicYear2
```

I tried all join query (ex JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, etc) but all of them return wrong results

Comment: What sql you using? (mysql, mssql ...)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: You must create a Temp Table with Dynamic Columns. Create there columns with every years

Comment: @RyanNghiem Thank you I will try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT om.ID, om.StudentID, om.[Student Name], om.SubjectName,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN academicyear END) as academicyear,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN class END) as class,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN term1 END) as term1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN term2 END) as term2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN term3 END) as term3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 11 THEN final END) as final,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN academicyear END) as academicyear,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN class END) as class,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN term1 END) as term1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN term2 END) as term2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN term3 END) as term3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN om.class = 12 THEN final END) as final              
FROM dbo.New_Portal_OldMarks om
GROUP BY om.ID, om.StudentID, om.[Student Name], om.SubjectName
```